# Divide decimal by decimal and get zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, decimal, division

Why when I do:

```
select CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(38, 28))/CAST(1625625 AS DECIMAL(38, 28))
```

Do I get 0, but when I do

```
select CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(20, 10))/CAST(1625625 AS DECIMAL(20, 10))
```

I get a value?

I would have expected the higher precision division to return a higher precision result, why is this not the case?

Comment: I tried it with oracle and they both return the correct value.

Comment: Updated the question - It's SQL-Server, my bad.  Upvoted :)

Comment: Nothing you can do about that. decimal(38, 28) is well into Floating Point territory and FP numbers are not accurate. Decimals are 'managed' floating point numbers and (20, 10) is just about within the manageable range, while (38, 24) definitely isn't! That's just how FP numbers work....Checkout the first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162624/indexing-float-values-in-python - trhe first answer give a good overview.

Comment: What is the highest precision/scale I can have then without going into 'Floating Point territory'?  I know FP numbers are approximations, but I didn't expect it to suddenly get that bad...   Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because for math operations the resulting precision and scale is calculated with the rules found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx#division

> *operation*
>   **e1 / e2**
>
> *result precision*
>   **p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)**
>
> *result scale*
>   **max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)**

So when using `decimal(38/28)` for both parts then you end with `decimal(105,67)` which is not supported so it get truncated.

***Also quoting***

> The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can always do this instead

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,28), 1 / 1625625.0)

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,10), 1 / 1625625.0)

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,28), 1.0 / 1625625)

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,10), 1.0 / 1625625)
```

All 4 queries will lead to same result. if you don't put .0 on one of two parts it will treat as integer division and only result will be converted to decimal.